# How to get value from a php array

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I am getting the following array structure after getting it in print_r statement :
It's from Magento. Can anyone please suggest me how to get **customoptions_qty**  from this array ?

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value Object
(

    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [option_type_id] => 13
            [option_id] => 5
            [sku] => 
            [sort_order] => 0
            [customoptions_qty] => 55
            [default] => 0
            [in_group_id] => 262142
            [dependent_ids] => 263141
            [weight] => 0.0000
            [default_title] => Buy 3 Get 1
            [store_title] => 
            [title] => Buy 3 Get 1
            [default_option_type_price_id] => 13
            [default_price] => 300.0000
            [default_price_type] => percent
            [default_special_price] => 
            [default_special_comment] => 
            [store_option_type_price_id] => 
            [store_price] => 
            [store_price_type] => 
            [store_special_price] => 
            [store_special_comment] => 
            [option_type_price_id] => 13
            [price] => 300.0000
            [price_type] => percent
            [special_price] => 
            [special_comment] => 
        )



)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the variable you printed is called `$_option`.
You can get `customoptions_qty` like this:

```
$qty = $_option->getOrigData('customoptions_qty');
```

You can get the full array like this

```
$origData = $_option->getOrigData();
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but you might be doing it wrong.
The _origData array in magento contains the values of an object as they were retrieved from the db.
If you modified the object you might want to use

```
 $qty = $_option->getData('customoptions_qty');
```

A Magento object looks like this

```
Class_Name Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        ( 
           //some values here
        )

    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            //some values here
        )
)
```

When you just get the object values from the db, _data and _origData are the same, but _data can change.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses magic callers/getters/setters for all of the values inside the `data` and `origData` arrays.

Whenever you attempt to obtain the value of a **camelCased** property name, the magic caller will attempt to get the value from the `data` array by using the **under_scoreifyed** property name.

If the value isn't in the `data` array the magic caller will try to find it in the `origData` array.

```
$obj->getCustomoptionsQty();
$obj->getData('customoptions_qty');
```

If you already set a new value for a certain property and want to get the original value for it you can by using `getOrigData`.

```
$obj->getOrigData('customoptions_qty');
```